# What design pattern do I use for this?

Tags: design-patterns

Say I am modelling this scenario - what design pattern could I use to best model this?

The base class is a CellPhonePlan. CellPhonePlan has two properties:

- int MonthlyPrice
- List of type string, StandardFeatures

Where StandardFeatures might include a value such as "200 minutes call time".

I also want to provide some addons to the standard CellPhonePlan. Such as

1) Family Plan

- int Price
- List of type string, Features

2) WeekendPlan

- int Price
- List of type string, Features

I want to be able to choose the StandardFeatures, FamilyPlan and WeekendPlan and have its price and features reflective of the options I have made. I also would like to know how to best represent this using a design pattern!

Thanks

---

Sorry I guess I didn't explain that too clearly. What I am after is having the base plan plus the family, plus the weekend. So all the values add up.

Answer (score 4):

No design pattern needed...

```
class CellPhonePlan
{
    int MonthlyPrice { get; set; }
    List<string> Features { get; set; }
}

var standardPlan = new CellPhonePlan
{
    MonthlyPrice = 10,
    Features = new List<string>() { "200 minutes call time", "texting" }
};

var familyPlan = new CellPhonePlan
{
  MonthlyPrice = 20,
  Features = new List<string>() { "500 minutes call time", "texting", "shared between a family" }
};

var weekendPlan = new CellPhonePlan
{
  MonthlyPrice = 5,
  Features = new List<string>() { "200 minutes call time", "but you can only talk on weekends" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could fit well into the [Decorator pattern](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf), if you really want to use a design pattern.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I'll now try to figure out how to mark it as the answer.